# What is this formula about (position vectors)?

Tags: vectors

I know this is about position vectors, but don't know exactly what its purpose is. It goes like this:-

$$\frac{(m\vec u + n\vec v)}{(m+n)}$$

Has anyone seen something similar to this?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$\lambda = \frac{n}{m + n}$$
Then
$$1 - \lambda = 1 - \frac{n}{m + n} = \frac{m + n - n}{m + n} = \frac{m}{m + n}$$
and
$$\frac{m \vec{u} + n \vec{v}}{m + n} = \frac{m}{m + n}\vec{u} + \frac{n}{m + n}\vec{v} = (1 - \lambda) \vec{u} + \lambda \vec{v} = \vec{u} + \lambda (\vec{v} - \vec{u})$$
which is simply linear interpolation between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$.

In other words, the expression
$$\frac{m\vec{u} + n\vec{u}}{m + n}$$
is [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) from $\vec{u}$ (when $n=0$) to $\vec{v}$ (when $m=0$).  Do note that $m = n = 0$ is undefined, because the denominator is zero, so at least one of them needs to be nonzero.

Geometrically, the point $\vec{p} = \frac{m\vec{u}+n\vec{v}}{m+n}$ is on the line between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ such that
$$\frac{\left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{u} \right\rVert}{\left\lVert \vec{v} - \vec{u}\right\rVert} = \frac{m}{m + n} \quad \text{and} \quad
\frac{\left\lVert \vec{p} - \vec{v} \right\rVert}{\left\lVert \vec{v} - \vec{u}\right\rVert} = \frac{n}{m + n}$$

Answer (score 0):

What the formula describes is a point on the line which goes through the points $\vec u$ and $\vec v$. Any choice of values for $m$ and $n$, as long as $m+n\neq0$, gives such a point.

If $m$ and $n$ have the same sign, then the point is between $\vec u$ and $\vec v$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but you said "goes through the points $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ ". But $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ aren't points, aren't they vectors??

Comment: @user545735 There is less of a difference than you might think. Vectors are just points with arithmetic tacked on. You usually draw a vector as an arrow starting at the origin, but could just as well be represented by just the end point. But if you want, you can say "the line through the end points of the two vectors" instead.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Arthur's answer is quite correct. Another way to interpret the expression is that it is a weighted average of the two points. Depending on the relative size of $m$ and $n$, you're weighting $\vec{u}$ or $\vec{v}$ more, respectively.

[EDIT]: As soktinpk mentioned in the comment to this answer:

> When interpreting $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ as position vectors, the weighted average is the center of mass of two objects located at $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ with a mass of $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Comment: When interpreting u and v as position vectors, the weighted average is the center of mass of two objects located at u and v with a mass of m and n respectively.

Comment: @soktinpk: Excellent!